# How to average of data over specific time period recoding the ending time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by, intervals

I need help with this.
I want to get the average of my data over a time interval using a specific time step for example 3 second intervals. So therefore, data is in one second resolution and I want to change the resolution to 3 seconds using the average values.

The Input:

| time | S |
| --- | --- |
| 2:30:01 | 5 |
| 2:30:02 | 9 |
| 2:30:03 | 450 |
| 2:30:04 | 7 |
| 2:30:05 | 10 |
| 2:30:06 | 300 |

This is what I was thinking... Alas, this is not changing the time intervals and the average isn't at the right index.

```
import pandas

step = 3  #3 seconds
df = df.groupby(df.index // step).mean()
```

Note: Please if you think there's another way to approach the problem I'm all ears.

Output:

| time | S |
| --- | --- |
| 2:30:03 | 154.7 |
| 2:30:06 | 105.7 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

```
import pandas as pd

from datetime import datetime, timedelta


x = [ ['2:30:01', '5'],
 ['2:30:02', '9'],
 ['2:30:03', '450'],
 ['2:30:04', '7'],
 ['2:30:05', '10'],
 ['2:30:06', '300']]


df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=(['time', 's']))
df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda t: datetime.strptime(t, '%H:%M:%S'))
df['s'] = df['s'].astype(int)

df_new = pd.DataFrame([{'start_time':interval_start.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), 
                        'end_time': (interval_start+timedelta(0,2)).strftime("%H:%M:%S"),
                        's': sum(rows['s'])/len(rows['s'])} 
                        for interval_start, rows in 
                        df.set_index('time').resample('3s',offset="1s")])
```

[out]:

```
    start_time  end_time    s
0   02:30:01    02:30:03    154.666667
1   02:30:04    02:30:06    105.666667
```

## In Long

First it's easier to manipulate time if you convert the string time type to datetime objects (or if you are Dr. Who =)):

```
df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda t: datetime.strptime(t, '%H:%M:%S'))
```

The heavy lifting is done by:

```
df.set_index('time').resample('3s',offset="1s")]
```

The `DataFrame.resample(...)` acts like a group by where you group by 3 seconds using `'3s'` and you have an offset of `1s`, thus grouping all your data points within the 3 secs interval.

And this converts the datetime object to the original string format of your timestamp:

```
interval_start.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

And to get the end time of the interval:

```
interval_start+timedelta(0,2))
```

Comment: Thanks Alvas. I tried it with a timestamp that also has a date and got this error. TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not float

Comment: If your original type is a datetime object already, then you don't need `strptime`. Try debugging the type error and change the code snippet I have a little. I believe in you =)

Comment: Also if you need a str instead of a float, try this `x = 3.142; print(str(int(x)))`